# Disk clean up script_error

Tags: linux

I am new to scripting and learning and i written a script as shown below to clear all logs under the path /usr/apache/logs

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/usr/apache/logs/"
for i in $(find $path . -name "*log*");do 
cat /dev/null > $i;
done
```

And after running above script i got the below Output error

```
/usr/apache/logs/
find: `./lost+found': Permission denied
find: `./root': Permission denied
l_clear.sh: line 4: /usr/apache/logs/: Is a directory
l_clear.sh: line 4: ./Backup/Clients/work_catalog: Is a directory
```

please help me why i got "find: `./lost+found': Permission denied" even i specified  the logs path.

Comment: As a new user I would discourage you from doing things like that in `/`, `/usr` and `/etc`. Practice on your home directory or `/var` or `/opt`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do log file maintenance with `logrotate`?

Answer (score 0):

change to root user and 
execute your script with root permission.

if use debian:
`$ sudo su
 # bash your_script.sh`

if you use fedora:
`$ su - 
 # bash your_script.sh`

Comment: @Hamidreza - Please add additional information to the answer by clicking *Edit*.